# How to display streaming result for Alfred Workflow?

Tags: streaming, workflow, openai-api, alfred

Im writing a Alfred Workflow to automate a streaming remote API call: With a given query, my remote server respond with text result in gradually and incrementally manner.

Lets take [ChatGPT as an example](https://github.com/openai/openai-cookbook/blob/main/examples/How_to_stream_completions.ipynb)

- if I hit "`call-gpt` what is an apple."
- I expect to receive

  - ["Apple"] (within 100ms)
  - and then ["Apple", "Is"] (after another 100ms)
  - and then ["Apple", "Is", "a"] (after 1s)
  - ...
  - until ["Apple", "Is", "a", "red", "sweet", "fruit"] (after 10s)

Its a bad experience that I wait for full 10 seconds for entire response to complete as LargeLangModel tends to be slow. I want to display the very first few response since UPL(100ms) is tolerable here.

So how can I imitate ChatGPT UI to make my Alfred Workflow display result gradually without buffer entire response?
It seems both Alfred ScriptFilter and LargeType has to commit computation result and cannot updated committed result. Is there any smart workarounds?